# How to pass item id and DropDownList selected item value to ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

So there's lots of good answers on here about how to pass a DropDownList selected value to an ActionResult. However I can't find anything about passing in the selected DropDownList value and the id of an item.

To illustrate, I'm working on a table where each row represents a project and the only user changable value is the status which is controlled with the dropdown list and button which triggers the update. The value of the dropdown comes pre-selected as the status column in the database is non-nullable. When the user clicks the button it should send the id of the item type in question as well as the status the user wants to change for the item so that the ActionResult can properly update the database

My current View code looks like:

```
<div id="divGrid" style='position:absolute; width:auto; padding-right: 5%'>
    <table id="checklistGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped grid">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ww)</th>
            .... // more table headings
        </tr>
        @foreach (var ww in Model.GroupBy(x => x.ww))
        {
            <tr class="ww-header">
                <td colspan="12"><span class="h2">@ww.Key</span></td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var manager in ww.GroupBy(x => x.manager))
            {
                <tr class="manager-header">
                    <td colspan="12"><span class="h4">@manager.Key</span></td>
                </tr>
                foreach (var item in manager)
                {
                    <tr class="row-header">
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ww)</td>
                        .... //more columns
                        <td>
                            @* ------------- Area in question ------------- *@
                            @{
                                List<string> ddl = new List<string> { "Done", "Not Done", "N/A" };
                                SelectList sl = new SelectList(ddl, item.status);

                                using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Checklist", new { id = item.ID, /* DDL Selected Value */}))
                                {
                                    @Html.DropDownList("StatusDDL", sl);

                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                                }
                            }
                            @* --------------------------------------------- *@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.applied_by)
                        </td>
                        @* [...] *@
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(int ID, string newStatus)
{
    //// Get the model
    //TaskInfo taskInfo = db.taskInfoSet.Where(m => m.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

    //// Update properties
    //taskInfo.status = newStatus;

    //// Save and redirect
    //db.Entry(taskInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    //db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Given the above how do I code it such that both the selected dropdown value and item.ID are sent to the ActionResult?

Comment: The `name` attribute of your `<select>` does not match the method parameter name. It needs to be `@Html.DropDownList("newStatus", sl);`

Comment: Herpa Derp, that was solution. Put that as an Answer and I'll mark it appropriately..

Comment: Note also if the view you have shown is `Index()` - i.e. you redirecting back to the same view in the POST method, your will improve performance by using ajax to post the 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList("StatusDDL", sl);` is generating `<select name="StatusDDL">` which does not match the name of your method parameter which is `string newStatus`. Either use

```
@Html.DropDownList("newStatus", sl)
```

or change the method to

```
public ActionResult Update(int ID, string StatusDDL)
```